# Open new console program with content inside in app with #![windows_subsystem = "windows"]

Tags: rust, tauri

My main program is a tauri windows app so I has `#![windows_subsystem = "windows"]` to hide the console. However I want to open another console program that was written in another language. I can do it with this code:

```
Command::new("mysecondapp.exe")
    .creation_flags(0x00000010)
    .spawn()
    .expect("failed to execute process");
```

The problem is this new program console content is completely empty. Any text on it does not show up at all. It simply show the console run until the end then close the console. I think it's because it inherits the `#![windows_subsystem = "windows"]` from the main app. How can I make it so it still shows the content?

Answer (score 0):

You should not hide the console if you want to show the subprocess output. You  can then [`pipe the stdout`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Stdio.html#method.piped) to read from it and show as you wish. Adapted from the [example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std_misc/process/pipe.html):

```rust
use std::process::Command;
use std::process::Stdio;
use std::os::windows::process::CommandExt;

fn main() {
    // Spawn the command
    let process = Command::new("mysecondapp.exe")
        .creation_flags(0x00000010)
        .args([])
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .expect("failed to execute process");

    // The `stdout` field also has type `Option<ChildStdout>` so must be unwrapped.
    let mut s = String::new();
    match process.stdout.unwrap().read_to_string(&mut s) {
        Err(why) => panic!("couldn't read wc stdout: {}", why),
        Ok(_) => print!("wc responded with:\n{}", s),
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question. Sorry the question is not clearer, I've added more information to it. Basically I want to the content on the new console to show up, not to capture the output of the new console and print it on the main console since I have to hide the main console after all. It's a windows program with UI and such so it does not make sense to have a console.

Comment: @BinhLuong, it should work just spawning the process. Are you getting any error at all? or what is the problem then?

Comment: it doesn't built, I got "method not found in `ChildStdout`" at read_to_string and your example above missing #![windows_subsystem = "windows"] which is required by my app.

Comment: @BinhLuong, no, I mean what is the ORIGINAL error you got. why does your code do not work

Comment: @BinhLuong, also, `Anything printed on it with Println does not show up at all.`, why are you talking about UI now? Please expand your question with all the relevant information.

Comment: I edited the question again. My code is working, it just the content of the new console doesn't show. I'm talking about UI because it's a tauri windows app, it has it own UI engine. Tauri app can run with console (mostly for development environment) or not with #![windows_subsystem = "windows"].